# (RaphaelJS) - How to Fill the inside of a path?

Tags: svg, raphael, vector-graphics

I have a path for the RaphaelJS library, I can't seem to get the fill to change its color.

```
var mypage = ScaleRaphael('mainContainer', 1000, 1000);
 mypage.setStart();
mypath.path('M794.33,21.5l152.3-0.76L946,21.5v-0.22l1.39,0.01l-1.17,206.61l-0.04,0.3l-0.15,0.27l-0.04,0.07l-0.18,0.35l-0.34,0.2 L786.4,321.59l-159.22,92.27l-2.12,1.18l-0.07-2.36v-1v-0.28l0.18-0.26l42.1-97.5l42.26-97.43l21.13-48.71l21.21-48.68 L794.33,21.5z M794.33,21.5l-41.46,97.76l-20.76,48.87l-20.84,48.83l-41.68,97.67l-41.78,97.59l0.18-0.54v1l-2.11-1.18 l159.08-92.46l159.23-92.21l-0.52,0.54l0.03-0.07l-0.14,0.57l2.04-206.6l1.39,0.01v0.22l0.13,0.77l-0.69,0L794.33,21.5z')
    .attr({"type":"path","stroke":"none","fill":"blue"});
```

The path is created correctly but the fill attribute only makes the stroke blue and not the filling, what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Where did you get that path? it's shaped like a stroke, if you do `.attr({"type":"path","stroke":"blue","fill":"none", "stroke-width":0.5});` you will understand what is going on.

Comment: Its the output from Illustrator, what can i do to fill the inside?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your path is shaped like a stroke, to make it fill modify the path by removing everything starting from the second `M`:

```js
var stage = Raphael('stage',1000, 1000);
var path = stage.path('M794.33,21.5l152.3-0.76L946,21.5v-0.22l1.39,0.01l-1.17,206.61l-0.04,0.3l-0.15,0.27l-0.04,0.07l-0.18,0.35l-0.34,0.2 L786.4,321.59l-159.22,92.27l-2.12,1.18l-0.07-2.36v-1v-0.28l0.18-0.26l42.1-97.5l42.26-97.43l21.13-48.71l21.21-48.68 L794.33,21.5z')
    .attr({"type":"path","stroke":"none","fill":"blue"});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/YzMCG/

Comment: The perfect answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There is quite a nice explanation here that suggests adding a transparent fill to the CSS in order to hide the coloured fill and make it look like a path only:

[Raphael Js can't fill path with Image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15924193/raphael-js-cant-fill-path-with-image)